# Searching for songs on an Android application

Tags: java, performance, android, singleton

In my application I need to search for some songs on my external storage card every now and then. On startup I read everything, however when it comes to new activities I thought I could just pass the file paths and read the songs I need again.

I've created this function:

```
public static Song getSong(Context c, String songPath) {
    Cursor audioCursor = c.getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { "*" }, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " = " + songPath, null, Media.TITLE + " ASC");

    if (audioCursor != null) {
        if (audioCursor.moveToFirst()) {

                String path = audioCursor.getString(audioCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                String title = audioCursor.getString(audioCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
                String album = audioCursor.getString(audioCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
                String artist = audioCursor.getString(audioCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
                int album_id = audioCursor.getInt(audioCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));
                int trackid = audioCursor.getInt(audioCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TRACK));
                Long duration = audioCursor.getLong(audioCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION));

                Song s = new Song();
                s.setPath(path);
                s.setTitle(title);
                s.setArtist(artist);
                s.setAlbum(album);
                s.setAlbumId(album_id);
                s.setTrackId(trackid);
                s.setDuration( new Duration(duration) );

                return s;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This function would either return null if not found or the song object created from the file's data.

1. Is it well-written?  Any improvements?
2. Is it better than using a singleton class?

Situation:

I click on a `ListViewItem` which represents an `Album`. It shows me a new `Activity` with another `ListView` which holds all the `Song`s from that `Album`. So I would just read every `Song` again via its path.

```
Intent i = new Intent( this, blabla.class );
i.putStringArrayListExtra( "paths", pathList );
```

When I use a Singleton class I would just set the selected `Album` to that Singleton class and read all the `Song`s from it again in the `onCreate()` method from the new `Activity`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general the code seems fine and it is not horrible or anything, but I think you could surely have improvements.

## High level

Currently your code returns `null` if `audioCursor == null`, I think this should be an exception, possibly an existing one, or a custom one. I'm not exactly sure what it does, so I cannot give more advice.

## General coding style

I suggest you to change your coding style to more consistent and I think you can enhance readability with some simple changes.

Take a look at:

```
Cursor audioCursor = c.getContentResolver().query(
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        new String[] { "*" }, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " = " + songPath, null, Media.TITLE + " ASC");
```

I understand that CodeReview is quite limited in width and your IDE is not necessarily so limited, but since you decided to split up the arguments, I would prefer it like this:

```
Cursor audioCursor = c.getContentResolver().query(
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    new String[] { "*" }, 
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " = " + songPath, 
    null, 
    Media.TITLE + " ASC"
);
```

This way all arguments are clearly visible and it looks consistent.

Similar arguments hold for:

```
String path = audioCursor.getString(audioCursor
        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
```

Here you are breaking up one argument, I would prefer to break it up outside, like this:

```
String path = audioCursor
        .getString(audioCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
```

Then lastly your blanks are off on this line:

```
s.setDuration( new Duration(duration) );
```

I'd say there is no reason to add them, it can even create confusion as now I start to think about the reason of the blanks, this is more clear:

```
s.setDuration(new Duration(duration));
```

## Early exiting

Currently you have all your code in the `if (audioCursor != null)` statement like this:

```
if (audioCursor != null) {
    //your code
    return value;
}
return null;
```

This leads to clutter and less space to actually type code because of the indentation, the preferred way would be to do so:

```
if (audioCursor == null) {
    return null;
}
//your code
return value;
```

This way you exit early and the rest of your code is not impacted by this flow.

## Variable naming

Most variable names look okay, except `Context c` and `Song s`, I see no reason to not use the full name like `context` and `song`, it will not harm anybody.
When taking a closer look, I actually noticed that `album_id` and `trackid` are also off, they are not consistent and neither in the recommended *camelCase*, they should be `albumId` and `trackId`.

## Code safety

I would recommend to make `Context context` and `String songPath` *final*, I would say it is important for `context`, such that you cannot accidentally reassign the `context` variable.

## Performance note

Currently you create a `new String[] { * }` on every method call, for maximum performance you could create a `private final static String[] STAR_STRING_ARRAY = new String[] { * }` and reference that one such that you do not need to create a new string array at every call. It depends on the amount of calls this method receives to see whether it is really worth it.

## One more high level look

After analyzing the code I see it can be decomposed into two methods:

- `public static Song getSong(Context context, String songPath) { ... }`
- `private static Song getSong(Cursor audioCursor) { ... }`

Where the latter would be called once you successfully have obtained the `audioCursor` and that one would do the low level job.

## Conclusion

My conclusion still is that the code overall is fine minus the coding style issues, but these improvements would improve it.
I think it is also better than a Singleton class, because this to me simply looks like an utility method, hence warranting a place in a `AudioUtils` class, but I do not see a reason for a Singleton class for this.